# List all JSON objects as list

Tags: javascript, json, discord.js

I have a JSON file named `point.json`, it has the following content:

```
{  
   "name":{  
      "points":1
   },
   "anothername":{  
      "points":2
   }
}
```

I'm trying to list the content of it after typing a command in Discord.JS like:

```
name: 1
anothername: 2
```

, I tried something like:

```
if(cmd === `${prefix}showwall`){

    let target = ??;
    let points= fs.readFile("points.json");
    let uWarns = points[target].points;

    message.reply(`${uWarns}`);

}
```

Is it possible to make this work?

Comment: file has `points` ... code has `warns` ... `'points' !== 'warns'`

Comment: Edited, however it isn't the solution

Comment: What is ?? Your code is too abstract

Comment: I just want to display a list of all users and their points by reading the JSON file and format it to display a list after using a command

Comment: @JaromandaX Dob wants to extract points for all users. Already knows how to do it for one player, but not for all users. So the question is, what should Dob put at '??'? A loop construct is required here though.

Comment: @Caramiriel could you help me out with an example? I haven't heard of that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
'use strict'

const points = require('./path/to/points.json')

message.reply(Object.keys(points).reduce((report, username) => {
  report += `${username}: ${points[username].points}\n`
  return report
}, ''))
```